# CSS Selectors not working

Tags: html, css

So I have a question about the css selectors in reference to my design.

I'm trying to fiddle around with how you can manipulate check-boxes through css by using multiple selectors such as "+", "~", etc to perform an event when the checkbox is either checked or unchecked.

I'm confused as to why this doesn't work, or by using "~" instead since from my understanding "+" selects elements matching it directly after the first element while "~" selects every element that comes after the prior element. This is my first time playing around with it so I'm not the best...but I'm trying to wrap my head around it. Does "element":checked not count as a reference point when stringing multiple selectors? I left two tried on the jsfiddle.

While this is intended to be a navigation menu later, I just, for the time being, left it like this to get a hang of selectors first.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
     <header>
          <input type="checkbox" id="navigation_drawer">
              <label for="navigation_drawer" id="drawer_open"></label>
              <label for="navigation_drawer" id="drawer_close"></label>
          <nav id="navigation">
              <ul>
                  <li id="home_page"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li id="about_page"><a href="#">About</a></li>                         
              </ul>
          </nav>
     </header>
</div>
```

CSS

```
label#drawer_open{
   position: absolute;
   top: 2;
   right: 0;
   margin-right: 1rem;
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/Nxafddw.png');
   background-image: no-repeat;
   width: 35px;
   height: 23px;
}

#navigation{
  background-color:blue;
}

#navigation_drawer:checked + #container #navigation{
  background-color:red;
}

#navigation_drawer:checked + container #navigation{
  background-color:red;
}
```

Thanks!

Edit: Man you guys are harsh xD Yes, I did make some mistakes copying and pasting this into here and in my code itself when I was changing it around. My fault. Here is an updated fiddle of the *original* problem for reference. I updated the HTML/CSS here as well. Thank you Pete for the updated fiddle. I would give it to you but since it's a comment instead of a reply I'll accept the other person's since it's another way as well. Thanks :D

https://jsfiddle.net/y9x8accc/6/

Comment: I can't see there is `id="wrapper"` in your HTML code.

Comment: Actually I called it "Container" but yea when I copied and pasted I missed the closing div. Sorry. Check op

Comment: How's this: https://jsfiddle.net/y9x8accc/2/, if you are absolutely positioning your labels, they don't need to be after the checkbox.  Or just use your sibling selector: https://jsfiddle.net/y9x8accc/3/

Comment: Please update the code, the HTML and CSS, in your question. Don't expect us to wander around the internet looking for your code in order to help you. For guidance please read the "*[MCVE]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines.

Comment: Yup you got it. I guess I got confused when I changed wrapper to container xD oops. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the `+` ([Adjacent Sibling Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)) selects the element that *immediately* follows it. In this case, the immediate element after your checkbox is your `#drawer_open` `label`, not the `nav`.

> **Adjacent Sibling Selector** This is referred to as an adjacent selector or next-sibling selector. It will select only the specified element that immediately follows the former specified element.

You seem to have incorrect indentation for your labels, so perhaps that made you think the `nav` is the direct sibling. In any event, you'd need to use the *[General Sibling Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)* (`~`).

The correct code to achieve what you want would be:

```
#navigation_drawer:checked ~ #navigation{
  background-color: red;
}
```

[Fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y9x8accc/5/)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)